# Closing a 'multipart/x-mixed-replaced' HttpClient connection

Tags: c#, silverlight, httpclient

I'm unable to close a connection to a 'multipart/x-mixed-replaced' MJPEG video stream. It has an unlimited content length because it's live video so the stream will never finish. Here's a sample of the follow code I use to grab the stream,

```
 var httpClient = new HttpClient();
 var response = await httpClient.GetAsync(url, HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead
 response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
 var stream = await response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync();
```

It's odd, if I go to this url (http://212.42.54.136:8008/mjpg/video.mjpg?camera=1) 15 times in chrome I will receive this error 'The maximum number of clients are already connected'. If I open up Fiddler and choose 'Abort session' I will be able to open another connection.

How do I do 'Abort session' with HttpClient like they do in Fiddler?

Answer (score 0):

You should do a dispose of all the objects, like in:

```
stream.Dispose();
response.Dispose();
httpClient.Dispose();
```

Btw. if you are interested there is a new c# library on CodePlex for a MJPEGDecoder running on Windows RT (Winodws 8.1 and Windows Phone). You can find the project [here](https://mjpegwinrt.codeplex.com/).